# Need to create column and add values (Date) to a that column SQL

Tags: php, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I need a command for create column  and add values(Dates)(YYYY-MM-DD) to that colmun

Thank you

Comment: So why not simply write one?

Comment: There wasn't much effort put into this question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you need to update an existing table, check out this guide:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Edit: To update a table in SQL you would use a query that looks like this:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value; --This line is not necessary. 
                              --You can add this if you wish to only update certain rows 
                              --e.g WHERE Date >= someDate
```

If you're creating a new table. I'd suggest check out the w3schools guides for CREATE TABLE, and INSERT.

Comment: Correct, although w3schools are pretty good about not changing their pages unless absolutely necessary. I honestly didn't feel the need to add such an obvious example as w3schools does a much better job than I could, however I've edited my answer to include an example in case anyone stumbles across this question in the future.

Comment: If you're going to downvote my answer, could you please provide a helpful comment on what you think is wrong with it? I'm not concerned with the reputation, I would just prefer to understand why some people think it's incorrect or poorly worded or whatever reason you have rather than having people just downvote and run. Thank you.